# Addition script - follow-up

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my latest version of my addition script. I have tried to take on all the advice I have been given by people like @Janos and @Hosch250 and also tried to keep to the guidelines set by the [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#fn-hi)  (I recommend it to anyone who hasn't read it yet). Now I have done it, so please tell me if I have missed anything/there is a way to improve.

```
def main():
    pass


def space():
    print(" ")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

    Previous1=0
    Repeat=True
    Numbers=[]
    space()
    print("Type 0 to end")
    while Repeat:
        AddNumber=float(input("Add a number: "))
        Numbers.append(AddNumber)
        if AddNumber == 0:
            Repeat=False
    for num in Numbers:
        print('{} + {} = '.format(num, Previous1))
        Previous1 += num
        space()
        print(Previous1)
        space()
        space()
    print('All your numbers add up to {}'.format(Previous1))
    input("/n Press ENTER to exit the program")
```

Comment: Also, I know I am going off on a tangent here, but is there a way to change the colour of the output text?

Comment: Did you actually read the PEP-8 guide? What did it tell you about variable namings?

Comment: You should use conventions

Comment: It is too late to edit it because it would invalidate the answer.

Comment: You should add a link to the last question so people can compare the two and see were you where compared to now.

Comment: @Ekult3k that question was deleted

Answer (score 10):

First things first, PEP-8 recommends `snake_case` for variable namings. So definitely `numbers`, `repeat`, `add_number`, etc. Also `Previous1` isn't a great name - what is the number doing there? Perhaps `sum_so_far`?

**Getting all the Inputs**

`input()` will raise `EOFError` when we run out of numbers, and the `float()` conversion will raise `ValueError` if the user enters not a float. Rather than having a sentinel value input (what if I want to do `1+2+0+4+5`?), just use what the language already provides:

```
def input_numbers(prompt):
    numbers = []
    while True:
        try:
            numbers.append(float(input(prompt)))
        except ValueError:
            # maybe print an error
        except EOFError:
            break
    return numbers
```

**main() and space()**

What is `main()` doing? I could understand:

```
def main():
    # all the logic here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`space()` is useless.